# Initialize constant of varying length to something other than all zeros/ones

Tags: vhdl

I am designing a simple LFSR with a variable polynomial for a randomizer. The lfsr length is being defined as a generic. I need to initialize the starting value constant as something other than zeros/ones. I've found the answer to this before, but I can't seem to find the answer again. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
entity GaloisLfsr is
    generic
    (
        g_LFSR_LENGTH : integer := 5
    );
  ...
end entity GaloisLfsr;

architecture zGaloisLfsr of GaloisLfsr is
    constant c_INITIAL : std_logic_vector((g_LFSR_LENGTH - 1) downto 0) := ((others => '0'), '1');
```

What is the proper syntax for defining a constant with varying size to something that a pure '(others => '0')' can't capture?

Comment: You need something like this? `BYTE<= (7 => '1', 5 downto 1 => '1', 6 => B_BIT, others => '0');`

Comment: @VinayMadapura That smells awfully like an answer to me...

Comment: @VinayMadapura, if you post this as an answer, I can accept it. This worked, but I don't think there is a way to add a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming one would like to initialize the 5-bit constant `c_INITIAL` to `"00001"`, then the declaration of the constant would be:

```
constant c_INITIAL : std_logic_vector((g_LFSR_LENGTH - 1) downto 1) := ((others => '0'), 0 => '1');
```

Comment: So this worked for that specific case, but now it is not working when I try to make my code modular. I have the generic from my post defining the total length and I declare the following `constant c_MSB : integer := g_LFSR_LENGTH - 1;` now when I perform the following, `ttapsToXor <= (c_MSB => '1', c_MSB - 1 => '1', others => '0');` I see the following error `(vcom-1048) Non-locally static choice (association #2, choice #1) is allowed only if it is the only choice of the only association.` This is a valid assignment considering c_MST is in fact a constant. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may convert natural/integer to vector

```
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
...
constant c_INITIAL : std_logic_vector((g_LFSR_LENGTH - 1) downto 0) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(g_polynomial , g_LFSR_LENGTH));
```

Comment: A bit string literal can express a value larger than can fit in type INTEGER. In VHDL -2008 that can have a decimal base.